# Quick parallel insertion performance on SQL Server (Identity or Unique identifier)

Tags: sql-server, performance, uniqueidentifier

I have to do some multiple inserts in parallel (from different users) into a table, and I want to know which solution is more efficient:

- using an auto-incremented ID
- using a unique identifier (generated before the insert by my application)

There are around 40 clients with an insert per second approximately

Comment: SQL Server tables are typically faster with a **well-picked** clustered index that conforms to the **NUSE** principle - Narrow, Unique, Stable and Ever-increasing. `INT IDENTITY` or `BIGINT IDENTITY` fits that bill - `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` does not (it's too random, and **not** ever-increasing, and tends to lead to many more very resource- and performance-intensive page splits)

Comment: Check out [Ever-increasing clustering key – the Clustered Index Debate……….again!](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/ever-increasing-clustering-key-the-clustered-index-debate-again/) - Kimberly Tripp is the *Queen of Indexing* for SQL Server and has an extensive list of blog post and research on the topic - go read it, well worth your time!!

Comment: With only 40 inserts per second, does efficiency even matter?